# In cardinality, what is the maximum number of relationships that a stroke indicates? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, stroke, cardinality

Just posting this in case anyone is trying to figure out the maximum number of relationships that a stroke indicates, as I have not been able to find anything regarding the topic on even IBM's own database site.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum number of relationships that a stroke indicates in cardinality is one.  As defined in Database Design & SQL for DB2 by James Cooper, *"Cardinality defines the number of occurrences of one entity for a single occurrence of the related entity. A stroke (|) indicates that the relationship is mandatory; the minimum number of relationships between each instance of the first entity and instances of the related entity is one.  The second or inner symbol indicates that the maximum number of relationships is one"* (James Cooper, 2013, p. 16).